# Sequencia Fibonacci

Tags: ruby, algoritmo

Estou fazendo processo seletivo, e eles estão me pedindo pra criar uma sequencia Fibonacci, só que não sei como criar, até tentei (código abaixo) mas não obtive resultado. Tenho que retornar o elemento F(0) da sequencia Fibonacci. alguém poderia me auxiliar ?

Código:

```
class Fibonacci
 def element (n)
  expect (Fibonacci.new.element(0)).to eq 0
  return n if (1..0).include? n
  (element(n - 1) + element (n - 0))
 end
puts element (0)
end
```

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178642/fibonacci-sequence-in-ruby-recursion/12178708)

Comment: Tentei criar desta maneira: def element (f)
        f = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = k < 2 ? k : h[k-1] + h[k-2]}
        puts f=(0)
    end
mas me retorna esse erro: 1) Fibonacci retorna o elemento F(0) da sequência de Fibonacci
     Failure/Error: expect(Fibonacci.new.element(0)).to eq 0

       expected: 0
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/fibonacci_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma.

Escrever a sequência de Fibonacci em Ruby:

```
x, y = 0, 1
10.times do
  puts y
  x, y = y, x + y
end
```

Em java:

```
class Fib {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
     int x = 0;
     int y = 1;
     int total = 1;
     for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       System.out.println(total);
       total = x+y;
       x = y;
       y = total;
     }
   }
}
```

Resultado em ambos os casos:
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55

Comment: Entendi como funciona !! Agora como que retorno o elemento do F(0)?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta dessa maneira Lucas:

```
   def fibonacci( n )
      return  n  if ( 0..1 ).include? n
      ( fibonacci( n - 1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 ) )
    end
    puts fibonacci( 10 )
```

Comment: Tentei deste jeito e também não vai. Me retorna esse erro:
$ rspec

An error occurred while loading ./spec/fibonacci_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: puts fibonacci( 10 )

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `fibonacci' for Fibonacci:Class
# ./lib/fibonacci.rb:6:in `<class:Fibonacci>'
# ./lib/fibonacci.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/fibonacci_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: Fiz o teste no repl.it e deu certo..  (https://repl.it/repls/AggressiveSevereRegression)

Comment: Realmente deu mesmo ! Eu fiz desta maneira , criando uma hash "f = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = k < 2 ? k : h[k-1] + h[k-2]}
        puts f=(0)  "
me da como valor nulo

Answer (score 0):

Gosto de raciocinar desa forma, espero que ajude:
1 - temos 3 posições : **antecessor, atual e próximo;**

2 - o **antecesso**r sempre receberá  o **atual**;

3 - o **atual** sempre receberá o **próximo**;

4 - o **próximo** sempre recebera **atual + antecessor**.

logo:

**antecessor = atual**

**atual = proximo**

**proximo = atual + antecessor**

Sou iniciante, mas espero ter ajudado. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib(n)
  return 1 if n < 2
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
end
```

Acho que não dá pra ser mais conciso.

No mais, pode encontrar várias outras implementações aqui: http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Ruby